# ThreadStateException: Thread has not been started when trying to join a thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

just recently i faced with such a question on an interview

what would be the output of methid 'Calculate' execution:

```
public void Calculate()
    {
        var threads = Enumerable.Range(0, 50).Select(x =>
        {
            var thread = new Thread(DoWork)
            {
                Name = x.ToString()
            };
            return thread;
        });
        foreach (var thread in threads)
        {
            thread.Start();

        }
        foreach (var thread in threads)
        {
            thread.Join();
        }
    }

    private void DoWork()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start()");
    }
```

i checked it in VS and was surprised that ThreadStateException is thrown on line 'thread.Join();'. using debugger i found out that thread is not started. 
it seems that when we go through the 2nd foreach we deal with another collection of threads. Can anyone please explain in details WHY exception is thrown?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You almost certainly don't want to create 50 actual threads.  That will have way more overhead than you'll want.  You should instead add 50 tasks to the thread pool to greatly reduce that overhead.  You can also use `Tasks` instead, which will use the thread pool by default and have an easier

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`threads` is an IEnumerable, not a  list, and enumerating `threads` calls the

```
var thread = new Thread(DoWork)
{
   Name = x.ToString()
};
return thread;
```

lambda 50 times, thus creating entirely new Threads.

If you wanted to distill the IEnumerable down to a concrete list of 50 threads, you'd need to call

```
var listOfThreads = threads.ToList();
```

and then use listOfThreads

Comment: +1. Oh, the ways that deferred execution can trip up the unwary.