# thread has not been started

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I am working on a basic threading program. I am relatively new to C# and WPF. What I am very basically trying to do is run a method inside of a thread so that I can get input while that method is running. If such input is received the program should tell the thread to finish its current object it is working on and stop.

My problem is that in no way can I get an indication that the Thread has ever started. Even when I try to have the thread run an infinite loop like,

```
while(true);
```

there is still no indication that the thread is running and I get a ThreadStateException when trying thread.join.

I have tried checking

```
thread.IsAlive
```

I have tried

```
thread.ThreadState == ThreadState.Running
```

I know the above isn't correct however I got desperate.

Constructed the thread like so

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(methodToRun));
t.Start();
```

I am positive the method is running, however the thread gives no indication that it is running.

In my research all I found that had to do with this error is 
[ThreadStateException: Thread has not been started when trying to join a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19793975/threadstateexception-thread-has-not-been-started-when-trying-to-join-a-thread)
which maybe I don't understand but the problem there seems to be that he was aborting before joining and aborting then starting again, I at no point abort the thread in my program.

Thank you all for your help, I will post anymore info needed or edit this post to fit specifications. I apologize as I am new.

Comment: Don't *ever* use `while(true);`. Furthermore, we haven't used the `Thread` class for years. Instead, use the `Task` class, or even the new `asnyc` and `await` keywords if you're using .NET 4.5.

Comment: The place to look for me would be `methodToRun`

Comment: Probably it is not the best way but it works and it is done that way in Linux processes. When you start the thread write this data to file. Then you read the file and understand that the thread is running. Delete info from the file at the end of the thread. Instead of file you can use database and in-memory database (.Net Dataset).

Comment: For indication that the thread ever ran, a break-point would probably work

Comment: Only reason I use while(true); is to ensure I am inside the method I'm running the thread on.

methodToRun only contains the infinite loop for debugging right now.

This program is being created on 4.0, I believe Task is new to 4.5 right?

Comment: @newuser6_10_14 can you place a breakpoint on that line in `methodToRun`? or at the start of `methodToRun` before running the program?

Comment: Do you want me to get more proof that the thread is running the code?

I am definitely entering methodToRun and it runs into the infinite loop (as I set a breakpoint and stepped through).

Comment: Task is in 4.0 so you should be able to use that

Comment: My problem was that I had reconstructed the Thread before running the Join(). So essentially the thread was a newly created thread when the program reached the Join() call.

This still confuses me however because I do not see how the thread could continue to run after being reassigned. Is there actually a separate instance of the Thread being created? Any clarification would be great!

I did solve my problem though. 

Also, what should I have added in my post so that this would have become more apparent?

Comment: Complete sample code would make question much better.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [`Task` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of the `Thread` class, as it's much easier and more up to date. You can call a method asynchronously as easily as this:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(methodToRun);
```

Furthermore, these `Task` objects can be easily cancelled using a `CancellationToken` (from the linked page):

```
var tokenSource2 = new CancellationTokenSource();

CancellationToken ct = tokenSource2.Token;

var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{

    // Were we already canceled?
    ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    bool moreToDo = true;
    while (moreToDo)
    {
        // Poll on this property if you have to do 
        // other cleanup before throwing. 
        if (ct.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            // Clean up here, then...
            ct.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }

    }
}, tokenSource2.Token); // Pass same token to StartNew.

tokenSource2.Cancel();
```

You can find out more from the [Task Cancellation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will keep the Task class in mind and learn it as to use this in the future. Much appreciated.

Comment: If this answer helped you to solve your problem, then please [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), as is customary on this website.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a simple flag that you set to `true` when you start the thread. If you are using .net 4.0 or higher you can also look into using the Task Parallel Library which supports cancellation. Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24118701/wpf-stop-backgroundworker-from-main-thread/24119127#24119127).

Comment: I tried using my own bool flag however when I try t.Join() I get the ThreadStateException "Thread has not been started."

Comment: you'll have to wait until the flag is set to `true`. Are you trying to `join` straight away or from a user driven action like a button press?

Comment: Yes from a button press, there is for than a few seconds between starting the thread and trying the Join()

Comment: maybe the thread is finished? If you are doing this for learning purposes you can try and put a `Thread.Sleep(2000)` in the work function. That might allow you to use `join`. But typically you set some sort of flag or cancellation token to stop a thread.